# Word for people who enjoy contributing to open / free projects

Tags: single-word-requests

I enjoy contributing to open, free projects like Wikipedia, Stack Exchange, and open source software development. I'm curious if there is a word for people who make a hobby of participating in such free and open projects that offer no payment or reward for contribution, except for reputation, satisfaction, or personal amusement.

The word "altruist" is the first that comes to mind, but it is a much broader term, and there are cases where it doesn't seem to be a perfect fit. For example, if you're answering this question, you are helping me and potentially others, but you may be motivated by reputation or **fun**, as opposed to merely a desire to give something away for free.

I'm not necessarily looking for a commonly used word, I'm more curious if there is a term out there for people who find enjoyment or satisfaction in participating in free communities.

I'm especially interested in a word that implies participation in open communities for *enjoyment* or as a *hobby*, as opposed to "charity," "reputation," or "ego."

Comment: There are various words related to the kind motivation behind it.  The one thing they all have in common is not doing it for money (non-professional).  Words like **amateur** cover that.

Comment: *Is there a word for people who make a hobby of doing unpaid work for others' benefit?* At least in North American English, they have ["sucker"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193420).

Comment: Traditionally the term would be "hacker", but that sense of that word got lost 40-odd years ago.

Comment: ..Open sourcer?

Comment: "devotee", enthusiast, contributor, donor, volunteer.. gotta mash em together .... devoteer?

Comment: Volunteer, Hobbyist

Comment: "Hacker" definitely carries (or once carried) the connotation I'm looking for.  It seems like a lot of the suggestions here are close but not as specific as I was hoping for.  Re: *amateur*, you can be a professional software developer and still be a *contributor* or *volunteer* on an open source project.  I like the idea of a neologism / portmanteau like "devoteer."  Still hoping there's an answer out there that contains that kind of intersectional meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Contributor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contributor) is commonly used by Wikipedia and FOSS (Free and Open Source Software) projects

> dictionary.com:
>
> 1. a person who contributes money, assistance, etc.
> 2. a person who contributes an article, story, etc., to a newspaper, magazine, or the like.
>
> The [Wikipedia community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_community) is the community of contributors to the online encyclopedia Wikipedia. Individual contributors are known as "Wikipedians".
>
> The aim of the [Harmony project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Harmony_(FOSS_group)) is to develop templates of Contributor License Agreements for use by Free and open source software (FOSS) projects.